# Atualização de app não requisitada pela play store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Boa tarde pessoal!

Após o lançamento do meu app na play store, publiquei algumas atualizações, no entanto, o botão de "Atualizar" não fica disponivel no meu dispositivo, apenas "Instalado".
A versão do app do meu smartphone é menor que a publicada na play store, no entanto, foi instalada direto pelo android studio (não pelo apk assinado)

Alguem sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Isso pode demorar senão me engano até 3 horas para a loja do google identificar a atualização.

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode acontecer pelo fato de você estar com a versão debug instalada. 
E na loja estar uma versão release.

Comment: Exato. As atualizações da Play Store só estão disponíveis para aplicativos instalados ***via Play Store***.

Comment: Boa, pessoal. Deve ser isso, o app não foi instalado via play store.